# Ctrl+Backspace in Delphi Controls

Tags: delphi, vcl

the `Ctrl+Backspace` keyboard shortcut normally deletes the word to the left from the caret. But it does not work in any of the standard Delphi controls you would expect (`TEdit`, `TMemo`, `TComboBox` ect.). Interestingly, `Ctrl+Delete` works just fine.

Does anybody know how to correct this behaviour easily?

I know that overriding the `KeyDown` procedure would do it, but this is a rather too complicated as `KeyDown` has to be overridden for every component.

Comment: This is not a Delphi-specific issue. Indeed, `TEdit` and the other controls are merely wrappers for the native Microsoft Windows controls, and they behave like this. Try, for instance, the edit box in Notepad's 'Select Font' dialog. Edit controls with auto-completion enabled, however, accept the Ctrl+Backspace hotkey.

Comment: Like Raymond [`said`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/10/11/5395501.aspx).

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. But it is still a little bit annoying because the shortcut works at so many places including even MS software.

Comment: @oxo: I agree, this is a shortcut I really expect and use daily, in most software. Probably the standard edit box hasn't got this feature by default because of some obscure and subtle compatibility issue with old (or misbehaving) software. Still one might wonder why there isn't a style one can use to enable this feature.

Comment: At the opposite side is *RichEdit control* where is this shortcut implemented by default.

Comment: @TLama: But that one lacks a built-in context menu, as discussed here a couple of days ago. It is too bad the standard controls 'lack' feature like this...

Comment: I'd be tempted to shove this in my own TEdit-descendant, or into TJvEdit.

Comment: Don't expect meticulous attention to these things from the current Delphi team (or is it just David M). In Delphi 12, The Find bar has a regular text box which is pathetic - no Ctrl+Backspace, no Ctrl+Delete. Hold F3/Shift+F3? It would display unable to find dialog over a dozen times (you having to press escape on each one of course). The IDE flickers everywhere when keys that do nothing are pressed (e.g. Escape). I like that LSP works better in Delphi 12 but the IDE still crashes daily with a clean IDE with 0 third-party components or extensions. MS needs to buy Delphi and sort this out...nah

Comment: The more I use Delphi the more I realise this is a dead-end. Archaic things dragged across from version to version. No components per project. Things are sluggish. Bugs left right and centre in every area, don't have to look hard. Delphi 11, Delphi 12, Delphi 13, 14 will be same buggy experience. MS absolutely rocks on the other hand, in almost every department. Why are we still using Delphi. If it's here by the end of the decade, I'd be surprised.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is not a Delphi-specific issue. Indeed, `TEdit` and the other controls are merely wrappers for the native Microsoft Windows controls, and they behave like this. Try, for instance, the edit box in Notepad's 'Select Font' dialog. Edit controls with auto-completion enabled, however, accept the Ctrl+Backspace hotkey. I think you can enable this easily by

```
SHAutoComplete(Edit1.Handle,
  SHACF_AUTOAPPEND_FORCE_OFF or SHACF_AUTOSUGGEST_FORCE_OFF)
```

(uses `ShLwApi`).

Comment: +1, I was writing a comment you to change the flag from `SHACF_DEFAULT = 0`, you were faster. It is the easiest way to implement this feature.

Comment: @TLama: Yeah, the actual autocompletion is probably not what the OP wants... Still, I wonder if there isn't a better way to do this. After all, it makes little sense to enable 'disabled autocompletion' in order to get the Ctrl+Backspace hotkey to work...

Comment: One should probably also add the flag `SHACF_FILESYS_ONLY`, not because it makes sense, but because the documentation explicitly says "This flag must be used in combination with one or more of the SHACF_FILESYS* or SHACF_URL* flags." referring to the flags I use above.

Comment: Nice trick! But, unfortunately sometimes the shortcut does not work. But it is definitely a good solution in cases where KeyDown can't be overridden. Otherwise it is possible to simulate Ctrl+Shift+Left and Delete keystrokes in KeyDown and ignore #$7F Char in KeyPress. Thanks!

Comment: The parameters do not really matter. If you replace the OFF with ON, ctrl+backspace still works. Could you help to comment?

Comment: Also, calling SHAutoComplete makes it impossible to detect "Enter" in Edit's KeyPress event handler. Could you help to comment how to work around this?

Comment: Also, after calling SHAutoComplete may not work correctly: TMaskEdit (deleting by ctrl+bcksp may block editing of deleted part); any DB-aware component (editing by ctrl+bkspc doesn't switch dataset into edit mode and edited value is not stored). Also TComboBox should be fixed in slightly different way. In other words it is safer don't use this function and keep default behavior of editors.

Comment: I recommend not to use `SHAutoComplete` for enabling these shortcuts. As pointed out above, several things break, including [pressing `Tab` does not do anything](https://github.com/HeidiSQL/HeidiSQL/issues/765).

Comment: Auto-completion in a find dialog has always been a nuisance to me. You're about to hit enter after typing your text quickly, and something got added right before you hit enter. A LOT of software these days caught on to the need to use Ctrl+Backspace et al. Also, better word-level navigation (Ctrl+Left/Right). In Delphi, extra keypresses always needed to get to the right place when moving to next/prev word. No customization/options for this. After so many years, very little has changed there. Windows Defender is a pain in the ass too. :) Good night.