# Is there a way to stop the annoying generation of OnKeyPress event with control characters when Ctrl+"some key" is pressed?

Tags: delphi, keyboard-events, delphi-2009

Start a new VCL Application, drop a `TEdit` on the Form and assign this to `OnKeyPress` event:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
 Caption:=Caption+' '+IntToStr(Ord(Key));
end;
```

When you run the application and press, for example, Ctrl+M or Ctrl+H you will receive control characters #13 (Enter) and #8 (Backspace) in Key `OnKeyPress` event. Is there a way to stop this annoying behavior ? I mean completely stop receiving `OnKeyPress` when I press shortcuts like Ctrl+M, not testing for Ctrl down and do nothing inside the event. I want my application to process Enter key when Enter key is pressed not Ctrl+M. I hope you understand what I'm saying...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305634/ctrlbackspace-in-delphi-controls

Comment: If I use `SHAutoComplete` I no longer receive #13 when I press Enter.

Comment: `OnKeyPress` event does not take into account special keys like `Ctrl`, `Alt` or `Shift`. If you want to be able to detect when one of them is bing pressed you need to start using `OnKeyDown` or `OnKeyUp` events instead.

Comment: I can test if Ctrl is pressed in `OnKeyEvent` and if it is I stop processing Enter key even if i receive Key=#13, but I hoped that there is a more elegant solution...

Comment: On the other hand, aren't those ctrl+key presses legitimate ways to type control characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `OnKeyDown/Up` events (`WM_KEYDOWN/UP` messages) receive individual keystrokes, reporting **virtual key codes** that have been translated from the keyboard's physical **scan codes** by the keyboard driver.

The `OnKeyPress` event (`WM_CHAR` message) receives **translated characters** after virtual keys and key combinations have been processed (if they translate into a character at all).

<kbd>CTRL-M</kbd> is *translated* into a carriage return (#13) character.

<kbd>CTRL-H</kbd> is *translated* into a backspace (#8) character.

This translation happens at the OS layer, when message loops pass keyboard messages to the `TranslateMessage()` function before calling `DispatchMessage()`.

See the following table for how various <kbd>CTRL</kbd> combination are translated:

[Control key - examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_key#Examples)

Also see [Character Messages](http://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~ygu/petzold/ch06d.htm) for a more detailed explanation for how `WM_KEYDOWN/UP` messages get translated into `WM_CHAR` messages.

So, to differentiate between <kbd>CTRL-M</kbd> and <kbd>ENTER</kbd> in the `OnKeyPress` event, you have to either:

1. use the `OnKeyDown/Up` events to keep track of when the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> (`VK_CONTROL`) and <kbd>M</kbd> (`VK_M`) virtual keys are being pressed versus when the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> (`VK_RETURN`) virtual key is being pressed.
2. Use `GeyKeyState()` or `GetAsyncKeyState()` to detect if the <kbd>CTRL-M</kbd> keys are held down versus if the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key is held down.

Otherwise, don't use `OnKeyPress` at all.  Use `OnKeyDown/Up` instead and do your own keystroke handling as needed.

Comment: Better than the Wikipedia link might be [this](https://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~ygu/petzold/ch06d.htm). Only a few shortcuts is actually translated into `WM_CHAR` (they are listed there in the table). [will delete this comment soon]

Comment: That link has an untrusted security certificate.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Certificate looks fine to me... I've seen some browsers flake out and reject perfectly good certificates from time to time, even from reputable and definitely well configured sites (apple.com, etc).  Not sure the cause but it seems likely the case here.

Comment: @J...: i am loading the page on a tablet. I have one browser that flat out refuses to load the page, not even an error message, just a timeout waiting for the page to load.  And another browser that says the certificate is untrusted, I think it is signed by a chain of authorities that are not known by my tablet (I don't recognize them by name, either).

Comment: I've had no problems with it. Here is [their CA](https://www.tu-chemnitz.de/urz/security/ca/ca-cert/). But anyway, what's behind is nothing more than a very old version of well known book Programming Windows by Charles Petzold. And just [this part](http://i.imgur.com/xuVoffM.png) might have been interesting for this thread (still valid after so many years).